# Run TestNG suite and @BeforeTest and @AfterTest not work

Tags: testng

I created a class with tests and in other class, I created before and after tests.
When I start `Suite.xml` with this annotation `mvn clean test -DsuiteXmlFile=Suite.xml`. First, execute `@BeforeTest` and my first test, and after that execute `@AfterTest`. After that, `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterTest` not run, just tests. `

```
<test name="exampletest1">
    <classes>
        <class name="Test2"></class>
        <class name="Test1"></class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

`

Comment: Could  you explain better please? Your test 1 runs correctly, but while running test2 before and after test annotations not run, is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<suite name="Suite1"> <!--@BeforeSuite runs here just once--> 
  <test name="exampletest1"> <!--@BeforeTest runs here just once-->
    <classes>
       <class name="Test2"></class>
       <class name="Test1"></class>
    </classes>
  </test> <!--@AfterTest runs here just once-->
</suite> <!--@AfterSuite runs here just once-->
```

If you want your "method"to run before each `@Test` annotation please use
 **`@BeforeMethod`** and **`@AfterMethod`** annotation.

From the [testng](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) documentation page we can see that

**@BeforeMethod:** The annotated method will be run before each test method.

**@AfterMethod:** The annotated method will be run after each test method.

Comment: Can you please tell what error you are facing? You have to use @BeforeMethod annotation

Comment: When i run test suite, first execute Test2 class, and work Before and After method, but in class Test1, not run Before and Afther method.

Comment: BeforeMethod and AfterMethod works for the class in which you put in. One way is to define these methods in separate class and let your Test2 and Test1 extend that class

Comment: Please accept the answer if this helps. It will help others also in future. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As said, @BeforeTest will run before starting @Test methods in **Test** in testNG.xml file.

```
<test name="Regression suite" >
```

@BeforeMethod will be execute for each any every @Test method in all classes. If you want to run only once in class use @BeforeClass: "The annotated method will be run before the first test method in the current class is invoked. "

similar for @After*